# MySQL Error inserting a row in a one-to-one relationship - (1452) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1452

I'm creating a DB in MySQL Workbench.
I created the schemas in an EER Diagram (in Windows), moved to Linux after that, and I did Forward Engineering for getting the SQL Script.
Now I'm testing the DB, but I'm getting this error in something that should be pretty straightforward as adding a row in the child of a one-to-one relationship.

These are the insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO `DB_local`.`User` (`idUser`, `name`, `surname`, `gender`, `bornDate`, `address`, `city`, `postcode`, `telephone1`, `telephone2`, `email`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '2020/01/01', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
```

That ran OK

```
INSERT INTO `DB_local`.`UserAdditionalDetails` (`idUser`, `cardNumber`, `userHash`, `entryDate`, `member`, `section`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '2020/01/01', '1', '1');
```

That got the error:

> ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`DB_local`.`UserAdditionalDetails`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_UserAdditionalDetails_User1` FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`) REFERENCES
>   `User` (`idUser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

**Any idea of why this simple INSERT is not working as expected?**

I searched it, and I saw in other questions people suggesting to "move" the AdditionalDetails data to the User table (that I would prefer to avoid, for design reasons), or to disable the referencial integrity before inserting in that table (that it's a hack, because it's something that should work fine).

For adding more context, this is the code generated to create that part of the DB (the DB is much more complex):

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema DB_local
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `DB_local` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema DB_local
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `DB_local` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `DB_local` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `DB_local`.`User`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DB_local`.`User` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB_local`.`User` (
  `idUser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(75) NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `bornDate` DATE NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `postcode` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `telephone1` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `telephone2` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`))
ENGINE = MyISAM;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `DB_local`.`UserAdditionalDetails`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DB_local`.`UserAdditionalDetails` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB_local`.`UserAdditionalDetails` (
  `idUser` INT NOT NULL,
  `cardNumber` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  `userHash` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `entryDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `member` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `section` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`),
  INDEX `fk_UserAdditionalDetails_User1_idx` (`idUser` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_UserAdditionalDetails_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`)
    REFERENCES `DB_local`.`User` (`idUser`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


 ... MORE TABLES ...


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: InnoDB table cannot refer to MyISAM table.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, seems that the issue was that I have some tables created with MyISAM and other ones created with InnoDB. Probably caused by the linux migration.
I updated the Engine to InnoDB in all the tables and it's working as expected.